# TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API calculate mAP for each label

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

When i evaluate the checkpoints,TF only shows the mAP over alls labels, but i need the results for each label.

My pipline.config:

```
eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1;}
```

I tried "all_metrics_per_category" and "include_metrics_per_category", but it doesn´t worked, so i don´t know if this would fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4778) on that here. It seems to be possible with a minor code adjustment (look in the comments for the complete instructions), but it's not officially fixed right now.